# MouseClick() on a locked VM

Tags: virtual-machine, autoit

I am aware that autoit MouseClick() would not work when the system is locked.
My Question is ::
I have VsphereClient installed on my machine and i access VMs using this client. Now if autoit script is running on VM and i lock my pc (VM is not locked), then will the mouse interaction functions work on the VM?

VM is not located on my local pc. It is located on an ESX server.
So if the VM is not in locked mode and my pc is in locked mode, will the mouseclick() of AutoIT work on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

vSphere is purely a configuration utility. It is not required for the virtual machines to run in anyway.

Therefore... If you have a script on your VM and that VM is not locked it would work exactly the same if you had it on a PC.

Don't make the mistake that vSphere is require for the machines on ESXi hypervisor to run.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanQ  Timmalos and Matt Horner

Answer (score 0):

If your VM is not locked and Autoit is running on your VM, the MouseClick() will work perfectly as it will only occurs on your VM independently of your current local pc state. In fact you must see your VM as another PC and since it's running and not locked you can do everything you want, in your case an autoit script.